# Monitor mode 802.11 captures on OSX

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm trying to determine the difference between capturing 802.11 frames in the following ways on OSX (10.8.5). It's a bit esoteric, but I use "Option 2" to capture frames for later analysis, and am wondering if I'm missing something.

**Option 1:** use "airportd":

> $sudo /usr/libexec/airportd en0 sniff

**Option 2:** use "airport" followed by tcpdump:

> sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport --channel=
>   sudo tcpdump -I -P -i en0 -w /tmp/capture.pcap (or alternatvely eliminate the -w and watch packets real-time).

From what I can tell:

- Both commands, according to the wifi icon on OSX, put the interface into 'monitor' mode.
- Both commands output a pcap file that is readable in both wireshark/tcpdump & Eye PA.
- Both commands appear to capture management, control and data frames.

The rub:
Option 1 disconnects you from the network. This is expected, when putting an interface into 'monitor' mode.

Option 2 **does NOT disconnect you**, provided you've set the channel to the same channel your currently connected to. This has a distinct advantage of keeping your connection up while capturing in monitor mode.

**My question:** Option 2 does not seem like it should work, or more specifically, it does not seem like I should be able to remain connected while also capturing frames in monitor mode. On a wired NIC, you can be 'promiscuous' and still send frames, though I didn't think the same was true for wireless NIC. I'm questioning the validity of capturing frames w/ Option 2?

Comment: This is mostly about OSX; as such, it's a better fit on [su].  Perhaps the community could vote to see whether they prefer to have it here or there.

Comment: I was debating where to place this myself. Shall I just mark it answered and post it over there? Thoughts?

Comment: @MikeA, I would leave it for now.  This community is young and still clarifying what is/isn't on topic to some extent and while the broad strokes are in, the details are sometimes to be decided.  I can see this fitting in here, as it is more about the differences in how one captures packets rather than about the underlying OS itself, although I can see Mike Pennington's point about it being largely OSX related as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to capture packets in OSX before, but if "Option 2" allows you to remain connected, this will limit your ability to capture as it is actually a "promiscuous" capture and not a "monitor" capture.  I would have to guess then that the OSX interface does not provide the distinction between the two and any "capture" is considered monitor (even when actually promiscuous).

Monitor captures require the capturing device to keep its radio in a passive listening state.  Promiscuous captures allow the capturing device to remain connected and transmit data and listen only when they are not transmitting (and depending on the driver, the capture may be filtered to the currently connected ESSID/BSSID/SSID as well).  Generally, monitor captures are what you want when capturing wireless data.

To explain what I mean, keep in mind that your 802.11 device can only transmit or receive on a frequency at any given point in time.  At the very least, to maintain the connection there are times when it will be transmitting, and quite probably there will be data sent by your device to the network in addition to that minimum.

While it is transmitting, there is no way for it to be capturing any data that may be transmitted by any other device.  Normally if there were two devices transmitting at the same time, this results in a collision, which you can sometimes determine by your capture.  If your capturing device participated in the collision, you wouldn't see that in any way but rather have the full data that was transmitted.

Comment: I've marked this as answered, most important point being "While it is transmitting, there is no way for it to be capturing any data that may be transmitted by any other device." Even if Option 2 is in fact 'monitor' mode, which it does appear to be, the radio can not Rx while it is Tx.

Comment: Apple may be calling it monitor mode, but among wireless professionals monitor mode and promiscuous mode have the specific meanings I indicated.  There have been many cases over time where developers use the wrong terminology because they didn't understand the differences.

Comment: True. To be technically accurate, the airport command sets the channel, and it's actually the tcpdump command that puts it into, what it's calling, monitor mode. man tcpdump and look for -I option (from either Linux or OSX).